# C++ string concatenation in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is deleting first string

Tags: string, c++17, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need help understanding what is wrong with my code or system. For some reason, when compiled and ran in WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux), the following code generates a wrong result. When ran directly in the windows command terminal, it correctly generates the final output as HNDPNV and in WSL generates PNV. The airports file is simply a series of 50 lines, with 3 letters per line. g++ version is 7.5.0 in ubuntu 18.04 WSL and g++ windows version is 9.2.0.

compilation flags are: g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -o test test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main() {

    string airport_designations[50];
    string air_companies_designations[20];

    ifstream airports;
    ifstream aircompanies;
    string name = "apple";
    string name2 = "orange";

    airports.open("Airports.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){

        getline(airports, airport_designations[i]);
        cout << airport_designations[i] << endl;

    }
    airports.close();

    aircompanies.open("Companies.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){

        getline(aircompanies, air_companies_designations[i]);
        cout << air_companies_designations[i] << endl;

    }
    aircompanies.close();

    name = airport_designations[4];
    cout << name << endl;
    name += airport_designations[8];
    cout << name << endl;

}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile using `ubuntu 18.04 WSL g++ 7.5.0` (or any other compiler): `test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:37:5: error: ‘nome’ was not declared in this scope
     nome = airport_designations[4];
     ^~~~`

Comment: ah. it's supposed to be name, i think i fixed that and forgot to add here.

Comment: Ok, now it compiles. In my environment it only prints blanks. You need to add the data files too - or turn the file streams into `istreamstrings` and put the data directly into the program. Btw, what function does `name2` have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line break on windows is \r\n,
On Linux \n.
To get a consistent conclusion, you need to replace all \r\ n in the Airports.txt file with \n.

Comment: I can't see linebreaks in the text editor i used (code was written in Sublime text in windows system) and the .txt files are plaintext. Do you know how i can force the file to show newlines?

Comment: Use Sublime to open Airports.txt. sublime: view-Line Endings-Unix, and then save.

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot.